# How to implement custom operator in cvxpy, e.g. quantum relative entropy

Tags: cvxpy

I have a convex function $f$ mapping two trace-one semi-definite positive matrices to a non-negative value. (since latex not supported, I put image just below it)

$$ f(\rho,\sigma)=\mathrm{Tr}[\rho\log(\rho)-\rho\log(\sigma)] $$

$$ \rho\in\mathbb{C}^{d\times d}, \sigma\in\mathbb{C}^{d\times d}, \mathrm{Tr}[\rho]=\mathrm{Tr}[\sigma]=1, \rho\succeq 0, \sigma\succeq 0 $$

[image]

The $\log$ above is matrix logarithm not elementwise logarithm. $f$ is called quantum relative entropy and is jointly convex (detail see [wiki/quantum-relative-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_relative_entropy))

$$ f(\lambda\rho_1+(1-\lambda)\rho_2, \lambda\sigma_1+(1-\lambda)\sigma_2)\leq \lambda f(\rho_1,\sigma_1) + (1-\lambda)f(\rho_2,\sigma_2), \lambda\in[0,1] $$

[image]

I want to implement this function in cvxpy but cvxpy don't have matrix logarithm (the matrix logarithm itself is not convex/concave).

If matrix logarithm is not available, Pade approximation can also be used, which requires matrix inverse. But I don't find matrix inverse in cvxpy.  (a matlab implementation is [github/cvxquad](https://github.com/hfawzi/cvxquad). Actually this repo implement the function $f$, and i want to migrate it to cvxpy)

More generally, how to implement a custom operator in cvxpy? say wrap a numpy function to cvxpy.

A reference scipy code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
def get_relative_entropy(rho, sigma):
    tmp0 = scipy.linalg.logm(rho)
    tmp1 = scipy.linalg.logm(sigma)
    ret = np.trace(rho @ tmp0) - np.trace(rho @ tmp1)
    return ret
```

What to expect: below I write a SDP problem to evaluate the so-called "quantum entanglement entropy" (fix `rho` and optimize `sigma`). When `rho` is the Bell state as shown in the code, the analytical result is known.

```
import cvxpy
import numpy as np

class CvxpyRelativeEntropy(cvxpy.atoms.Atom):
    def __init__(self, rho, sigma):
        super().__init__(rho, sigma)
        # TODO cvxpy magic

# quantum entanglement entropy for Bell state, Isotropic state with d=2
# 0*log(0)=0
rho = np.array([[1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1]])/2
sigma = cvxpy.Variable((4,4), complex=True)
constraint = [sigma>>0, cvxpy.trace(sigma)==1, cvxpy.partial_transpose(sigma,[2,2])>>0]
obj = cvxpy.Minimize(cvxpy.real(CvxpyRelativeEntropy(rho, sigma)))
prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, constraint)
prob.solve()

# the solution should be (analytical result)
# prob.value=0.69314718
# sigma.value == np.array([[2,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [1,0,0,2]])/6
```

Comment: You first have to ask yourself if the operator you want to define can be converted to a representation that any solver used by CVXPY will understand. In the case of relative quantum entropy there is no such solver under CVXPY. To convert the approximation from cvxquad to cvxpy you just have to repeat step by step what they do,  in particular how they fit the problem into DCP form. Neither CVX nor CVXPY "has" a matrix inverse, both of them have to model it internally through a Schur complement SDP model. If it can be done in CVX then it can be done the same way in CVXPY.

Comment: Regarding "wrapping an arbitrary numpy function" in CVXPY, to do this you first have to express your function as a disciplined convex programming model and for most numpy functions for which this is possible and reasonable it has already been done and appears as some cvxpy atom.

Comment: thx for the advice, i will go through cvx/cvxquad implementation details